# Scheduled reminders on membership end date not sending

Tags: scheduled-reminders

CiviCRM 4.7.28, Drupal 7

Scheduled reminders send if set for a specific date fine, but aren't triggered by membership end date - am i perhaps doing something wrong?

[image: Scheduled Reminder Settings]

I have a relevant membership ending on 30/09/2019 hence the hours to test, but tried with days too.

Unless scheduled reminders are created on the membership creation, so not retroactive?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I posted a summary [**HERE**](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/285#note_9593) just yesterday that should provide you with way too much detail as to the cause of the issue, but by far the easiest way to fix the issue for existing records is to enable repetition (being sure to enter every 1 year until 0 days before membership end or the scheduled job will get mad and won't run).

In the "Current Behavior" section of the same post, you will find a detailed description of how to test to make sure schedule reminders will continue to work - if you don't have access to the database and want to be completely sure that the renewal reminders will send when expected, the next easiest option would be to create new schedule reminders and disable the old ones.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Thanks - at first check i don't think this is the same issue i'm having, or not directly anyway, but i'm going to check through all that info either way.

Comment: The whole of the Schedule Reminder functionality appears to be fraught with problems. More often than not reminders don't get sent and generate fatal errors in my experience. A great idea, and much needed, but poorly implemented.